# Open GUI linux terminal in non-interactive mode

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, terminal, interactive

It would be helpful if I can open a terminal and run commands exactly as if they would be run by a non-interactive bash script, to test whether certain commands work in non-interactive mode without having to make a script for it. Is this possible?

To be clear I don't mean to set the terminal to non-interactive mode after having started, since at that point it will already have run e.g. `.bashrc` thereby changing the environment.

For example, suppose I have a command `test_command file1.txt`, but `test_command` is defined in `.bashrc`. Then since in non-interactive mode the command won't be found, it shouldn't work in this terminal either.

Comment: please edit your Q to show an example command.

Comment: First, you seem to be mixing up "terminal" and "shell". Terminal, by its very nature, is an interactive device. A shell can be an interactive or a non-interactive one, I presume you want to have a non-interactive shell in the terminal. You can set `bash --norc` or alike as a custom command in your terminal's setting. But then again, you want to type commands to that shell in an interactive fashion, don't you? Doesn't this automatically make this an interactive shell? Alternatively, you can skip the interactive shell altogether by specifying your shell script as the custom command.

Comment: @egmont, "__But then again, you want to type commands to that shell in an interactive fashion, don't you?__" Yes I still want to interact with the shell interactively, but I want the shell not to know that that is happening. So I want to interact with a shell via a terminal, where the shell is interacting with input and output streams that it thinks are from some non-interactive source.

Comment: Then I assume you want no prompt to be printed (since non-interactive shells don't print one), no line editing capabilities (same reason)? Try the command `bash /dev/stdin`, is this what you're looking for?

Comment: @egmont, oh that seems like it might be what I'm looking for yes (though I don't know what it actually does under the hood. Also I admit I didn't know that it's the shell that prints the prompt, rather than the terminal. It would be nice for the terminal to still print the prompt, i.e. add some text before the shell's output, which the shell doesn't know about. But it's not strictly necessary).

Comment: The terminal doesn't (and shouldn't) do anything on its own. The terminal's job is to blindly and faithfully execute the exact commands that it receives from the app(s) running inside. Any deviation and the app's intent is likely to fall apart big time. A rough analogy is that terminals are like web browsers, and the apps inside (including the shell) are like remote webpages. A terminal has no idea what is a "shell" and what is a "prompt". It just executes a command and paints whatever that command outputs.

Comment: @egmont, makes sense. Is there a description of exactly what `bash /dev/stdin` does? One reason I'm confused is that every program instance has a stdin, so I'm not sure what `/dev/stdin` is pointing to.

Comment: `bash filename` tells `bash` to process the script contained within `filename`. `/dev/stdin` is the standard input of each process. Combine this two.

Comment: @egmont, oh so `/dev/stdin` is not in fact a single file, but when process X accesses it, it points to the stdin of process X? In that case it makes sense.